# Estimating a quantity from noisy value and accurate measurements of its derivative

Tags: estimation

I'm trying to write a good estimator $\hat{n}_n$ for a real time series $x_n$ from a set of

- noisy measurements $a_n = x_n + m_n$ (here $m_n$ is a high-level noise), and
- accurate measurements of its derivative $b_n = (x_n - x_{n-1}) \delta t + p_n$ (where $p_n$ is a low-level noise).

Is there any standard (and simple) way of performing this simple task, and to get an estimate of the error $\sigma_n^2 = \mathbf{E}[(\hat{x}_n - x_n)^2]$?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers,

Jb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.